# T-SQL get multiple SUM from subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It's my first question to such forum. I was looking for answers, but I did not find a similar issue.

This is a sample data from my SQL Server table:

```
typ field1  field2  field3
--------------------------
IN  johny   bravo   123
IN  mickey  mouse     5
IN  mickey  mouse    70
OUT johny   bravo    20
OUT mickey  mouse    15
```

What I need to select is:

```
field1  | field2    |   sum(field3) where typ='IN'  |   sum(field3) where typ='OUT'
```

That's what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT
    t.field1,
    t.field2,
    SUM(t1.total) AS total_in
    SUM(t2.total) AS total_out
FROM
(
    SELECT
        'IN' as typ,
        field1,
        field2,
        SUM(field3) AS total
    FROM XYZ
    LEFT JOIN some_table ON ...
    WHERE condition=1
    GROUP BY typ, field1, field2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        'OUT' as typ,
        field1,
        field2,
        SUM(field3) AS total
    FROM XYZ
    LEFT JOIN some_table ON ...
    WHERE condition=2
    GROUP BY typ, field1, field2
) t
LEFT JOIN t t1 ON t.field1 = t1.field1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t.field1 = t2.field1
GROUP BY 
    t1.field1,
    t1.field2
```

But when I run this query I get an error

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name t

and I simply don't know how to get this query to work.

I will be grateful for your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.field1,  t.field2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'IN' THEN field3 ELSE 0 END) AS total_in,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OUT' THEN field3 ELSE 0 END) AS total_out
FROM . . .
GROUP BY t.field1, t.field2;
```

You can also do this with `pivot`.

Comment: Wow! 17 seconds and i get the right answer. Thank you Gordon Linoff ... but this answer made me realize how small I am :)